# Python Count Process Blocks from Log Data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some logs in this manner. Given new line just for better understanding.

```
[2022-04-25 06:24:22,417][Open WebSite [Executing] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:25,028][Launch the  Browser [Executing] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:26,046][Launch the  Browser [Closed] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:32,532][NavigateTo login page [Executing] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:33,532][NavigateTo login page [Closed] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:34,549][Open WebSite [Closed] ] [5198] [5658] [1]

[2022-04-25 06:24:35,551][Login [Executing] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:36,692][Entering email Address [Executing] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:37,715][Entering email Address [Closed] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:38,811][Entering password [Executing] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:39,822][Entering password [Closed] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:41,012][Click on Login [Executing] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:42,027][Click on Login [Closed] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:43,029][Login [Closed] ] [5198] [5658] [1]

[2022-04-25 06:24:44,030][Read Data [Executing] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:45,146][Click on Shipment Dashboard [Executing] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:46,149][Click on Shipment Dashboard [Closed] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:47,227][Get Html DataTable [Executing] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:48,228][Get Html DataTable [Closed] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
[2022-04-25 06:24:49,231][Read Data [Closed] ] [5198] [5658] [1]
```

The data is in away that each newline separated logs is part of one process. I want to count the number of process present in the given logs. The logs data is pretty extensive but it's structure remains consistent.

```
Expected Output:

number_of_blocks = 3
Example:
block 1 : Open WebSite [Executing] to Open WebSite [Closed]
block 2: Login [Executing] to Login [Closed]
block 3: Read Data [Executing] to Read Data [Closed]
```

What's the best possible solution in Python?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic way would be:

```
line_count = sum(1 for line in open('logs.txt'))
```

**Updated answer:**

Since you want the output in the format you mentioned, and assuming the structure of the log file strictly remains the same, here's one naïve way to do it.

```
import re

line_count = 0 
blocks = []

with open('logs.txt') as f:
    regex = r"\[(.*?)\]"
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    
    for line in f:
        pattern = re.compile(regex)
        
        bracket_texts = list(re.findall(pattern, line))
        group_len = len(bracket_texts)
        first = bracket_texts[1] + "]" + " to "
        last = bracket_texts[group_len - 4] + "]"
        blocks.append(first+last)
        line_count += 1

print(f"number_of_blocks = {line_count}")
for number, block in enumerate(blocks, start = 1):
    print(f"block {number} : {block}")
```

Comment: Thanks @Ravindra S, but your answer just outputs the line count.

Comment: @n0thingButLinear I've updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: The output I am getting is:

number_of_blocks = 20
block 1 : Open WebSite [Executing] to Open WebSite [Executing]
block 2 : Launch the  Browser [Executing] to Launch the  Browser [Executing]
block 3 : Launch the  Browser [Closed] to Launch the  Browser [Closed]
block 4 : NavigateTo login page [Executing] to NavigateTo login page [Executing]
........ and so on until block 20

Expected output should be:
number_of_blocks = 3
block 1 : Open WebSite [Executing] to Open WebSite [Closed]
block 2 : Login [Executing] to Login [Closed]
block 3 : Read Data [Executing] to Read Data [Closed]

Comment: Then you need to share the exact sample of the log file to start with. Based on what you put in the question, the file I am working with is this: https://file.io/OpIuSP0TGxy2 You can host your sample on that same website and perhaps add the link to the question.

Comment: @n0thingButLinear I'd appreciate a response from you.

Comment: here is the file. https://file.io/8IEbx5HE9B6L

Comment: With that format, it seems really challenging one to solve. I thought there is newline between the blocks' logs. Sorry I won't be able to help much as of now.